# Advice on SIPO FIFO clock, as well as 555 timer usage

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, flipflop, 555, memory

I've made a circuit which involves me entering inputs, and the result being displayed in a seven segment LED. The LED must flash on and off and display the input number at least two times in two seconds, and one must be able to keep entering inputs whilst it is flashing. For example, if I entered '10010110' it should display '9' for two seconds, then display 6 without needing any further input. (Basic block diagram shown here)[image]

I've added a 4 bit Serial-in-parallel-out shift register is used for the input and a 4 bit wide FIFO for storage before it feeds into the output. For this, should I use the clock cycle that I desire for the output (ie two seconds for high and low) by function generator, or should I use 1 shot monostables for the buttons and use something like a 555 for the output.

I cannot really use any complex things like microcontrollers. Any advice/help appreciated.

Comment: Adam X - Hi, Other site members have noticed that this is a repost of a previous question (after it was edited). It also seems to be related to a series of (apparently) overlapping questions that you have asked (some now deleted, some still visible). In short, things are a bit confusing :-( It's generally a bad idea having multiple questions open at the same time, on related topics - since an update on one question may not be seen by people trying to help on another, related, question. In short: Please add links between relevant questions, avoid overlaps, show progress based on Q 1 in Q 2 etc.

Comment: You need to store 8 bits as 2 , 4 bit nibbles and MUX these 4 bits with a timer after word latch is decoded or received.  Meaning Async or Sync with dedicated bit and word clock